# How center icon vertically

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I read lot of solution for kind of problem, but I don't find a solution

I've table like

```
<td class="thSorter ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-state-default" style="width: 100px; min-width: 100px; max-width: 100px;">Dte Naissance<i class="ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s"></i></td>
```

and css

```
  .TFO thead tr td 
{
     text-align:center;
}

.TFO thead tr td .ui-icon
{
    float: right;
    margin-top:-8px;
}
```

When My text is in 2 lines it's good like here, but if it's on 1 line it's to hight.

See for more information [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfjyLvpc/)

Comment: Looks fine on Chrome and IE11?

Comment: You don't see double arrow on Dte cell. It's a litlle higth. Even with Chrome and IE11 (Windows 8 or 7 like you want, I try)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't float your element. Use positioning instead:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/bfjyLvpc/1/)

```
tr td {
  text-align: center;
}
tr td .ui-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  right: 5px;
}
tr.trheader {
  height: 35px;
  max-height: 35px;
  min-height: 35px;
}
td {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: transparent;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<table class="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-top">
  <tr class="trheader">
    <td class="thSorter ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-state-default" style="width: 110px; min-width: 110px; max-width: 110px;">Dte Naissance<i class="ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s"></i>

    </td>
    <td class="thSorter ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-state-default" style="width: 100px; min-width: 100px; max-width: 100px;">Dte<i class="ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s"></i>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

[Demo with simple animation effect](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/bfjyLvpc/2/)

Comment: It's run on Chrome but not with IE11

Comment: @YannickIngenierie: could you please advise on what's wrong?

Comment: On IE11 , the arrows aren't on the same line :-( On Dte cell, arrow is to up

Comment: A display good : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfjyLvpc/4/) but I don't know when header is written on one or two line. Then when add my span with line-height

Answer (score 0):

I just find look here[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfjyLvpc/8/)

```
 <table class="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-top">
    <tr>
        <td class="thSorter ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-state-default" style="width: 110px; min-width: 110px; max-width: 110px;">

            <div style="display: table;">
                <div  style="display: table-cell; height: 30px; vertical-align: middle;width:90%">Dte Naissance</div>
                <div style="display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"><i class="ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s"></i></div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="thSorter ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-state-default" style="width: 100px; min-width: 100px; max-width: 100px;">
            <div style="display: table;">
                <div  style="display: table-cell; height: 30px; vertical-align: middle;width:90%">Dte</div>
                <div style="display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"><i class="ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s"></i></div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<style>
    tr td
    {
        text-align: center;
    }

    tr.trheader
    {
        height: 35px;
        max-height: 35px;
        min-height: 35px;
    }

    td
    {
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: transparent;
        padding-right: 5px;
        padding-left: 5px;
    }
</style>
```